# Fail try/catch block reading a csv

Tags: c#, unit-testing, csv, try-catch, csvhelper

I'm unit testing my C# application that Parses a CSV. I'm at 94% code coverage, because I can't force it to fail the try/catch blocks... I'm using CsvHelper from Nuget http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper

```
public void ParseCsv([FromBody] string csvText)
{
    var parseCsv = new XsvData(new[] { "\t", "," });
    try
    {
        using (var reader = new XsvReader(new StringReader(csvText)))
        {
            parseCsv.Read(reader, headerExists: true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            Content = new StringContent("Unable to read CSV."),
            ReasonPhrase = "Invalid CSV"
        };

        throw new HttpResponseException(response);
    }
}
```

I've tried passing the most obscure strings I could think of to it, but it makes it through this, and errors out later on in the function..

```
[TestMethod]
//[ExpectedException(typeof(HttpResponseException))]
public void TestUploadCsv_UploadingCsvNonCsv()
{
    const string csvText = "fhfhk@- jhjfh@ajh- fjkqeqir%hjewq@hf- ujewqh$phfuw \n hfwu- ihfq&if*u@q- afuhwu- fhiue@wfhiuewhiuf";
    var context = GetMyFakeEntityDatabase();
    var controller = new MyController(context);
    controller.ParseCsv(csvText);
}
```

After the try/catch blocks, I have a section that enforces all the headers exist, and it fails there, but it should be failing during the reading, for this example. How do I force my unit test to fail? Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for testing how the code handles failures.

Comment: You could pass `null` for `csvText`.

Comment: @juharr The way it's currently written, that would work, but it's not a very generic solution.  What if he wants different status codes for a null/empty string vs. invalid syntax.

Comment: @CleverNeologism Then he would have to change his code and add corresponding tests.

Comment: @juharr I have no idea how I didn't think of just null. I was so busy trying to make a long bogus string I guess. That worked though. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by just passing it null, like juharr recommended in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Provider Pattern and interfaces instead of concrete types, then run your unit tests by substituting mock objects that will throw the exceptions.

In detail:

- Extract Interface `IXsvReader` from `XsvReader`
- Implement a new concrete instance of `IXsvReader` that throws exceptions on `Read`.  Create one concrete implementation class for each error you expect to handle separately (in this case, you only need one).
- In the class that contains the `ParseCSV` method, have a property for an `IXsvProvider` that is settable.  In the constructor for that same class, set that property to a default provider that will return a "real" reader.  This interface has only one method, `GetXsvReader(string text)`
- In your test class, new up the class with the ParseCSV function, then inject an IXsvProvider(s) that returns your "dummy" `IXsvReader` that simply throws exceptions whenever you try to use the method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Inversion of Control` and inject the dependency into the controller instead of creating it in controller action. This way you can mock out the reader, and have it throw an except instead.

I'm going to write this example in terms of `CsvHelper` since that's what you say you are using, even though the example doesn't look like it.

Roughly:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICsvReader csv;

    public MyController( ICsvReader csv )
    {
        this.csv = csv;
    }
}

public class CsvReaderMock : ICsvReader
{
    public void Read()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Now you can use your mock `ICsvReader` when testing, and it will throw an exception.

Also, you should only ever test a single method. If your method has dependencies, you should be passing them in instead of creating them, so you can test only the code in that method, and not of the classes it creates.